# A build-system independent way to get the version from a package source directory

Tags: python, versioning, python-packaging, pep517

There are many different ways that Python packages manage their version data. Is there a build-system independent way to extract the version from a package source directory?

I'm aware of the [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) compatible Python package builder [`build`](https://github.com/pypa/build) which does this internally. For instance, in an example source directory for a Python package `my_pkg`:

```
$ python -m build --sdist
...
Successfully built my_pkg-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

so is there a clever way to just extract the version number without building the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The only [mandatory hooks](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#mandatory-hooks) currently specified for a PEP 517 build backend are the build hooks:

```
def build_sdist(sdist_directory, config_settings=None):
    ...

def build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings=None, metadata_directory=None):
    ...
```

The build process also generates the package metadata, including the [Version](https://peps.python.org/pep-0345/#version) field. In the general case, it is necessary to execute a build to get the version info.

Note that it's also fairly common for the version info to be generated dynamically, e.g. sourcing it from the underlying [version control system](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/), so discovering the version from the source directory without a build would only be possible in a subset of cases anyway.

Some build backends may provide other ways to get the version, for example in setuptools you could use:

```
python3 -c 'import setuptools; setuptools.setup()' --version
```

However, PEP 517 has nothing to say about this, and it will be specific to the build backend.

For a backend-agnostic way to generate the version, you could use [`build.util.project_wheel_metadata`](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-build.util), but this may actually execute a build.