# Is there something like python setup.py --version for pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

With a simple `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1.2.3',
)
```

I can do

```
$> python setup.py --version
1.2.3
```

without installing the package.

Is there similar functionality for the equivalent `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[project]
name = "foo"
version = "1.2.3"
```

Comment: I've found `tomlq .project.version pyproject.toml | tr -d \"` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get \`setup.cfg\` metadata at the command line (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271825/how-to-get-setup-cfg-metadata-at-the-command-line-python)

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592060/makefile-how-should-i-extract-the-version-number-embedded-in-pyproject-toml and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506836/is-there-a-way-to-extract-project-metadata-without-pip-installing-it

Comment: `pyproject.toml` isn't specific to any particular build tool, so your answer will depend on what build tool you are using.

Comment: `setup.py` itself *is* an ad hoc build tool.

Comment: @chepner but isn't (shouldn't) version be a core piece of meta-data that should be common for all build tools..?

Comment: The version is metadata about the *project* which is *independent* of the build tool. `setup.py` acted as both the configuration file and the tool that read configuration data (from itself). Once the configuration is separated from the build tool, the "real" answer to the question is "read `pyproject.toml`", but there are now many different ways you might do that, instead of the one "obvious" way you had with `setup.py`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73310593/674039

Comment: Maybe dupe: [A build-system independent way to get the version from a package source directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75179517/674039)

Comment: @wim they're at least related, but it seems the lack of a simple way to get core package metadata is a pervasive problem (cf. https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/348 mentioned by sinoroc below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python 3.11+, something like this should work:

```bash
python3.11 -c "import tomllib; print(tomllib.load(open('pyproject.toml', 'rb'))['project']['version'])"
```

This parses the TOML file directly, and assumes that [*version*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#version) is not [*dynamic*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dynamic).

---

In some cases, *version* is declared *dynamic* in `pyproject.toml`, so it can not be parsed directly from this file and a solution (the only one?) is to actually build the project, or at least its *metadata*.

For this purpose, we can use the [`build.util.project_wheel_metadata()`](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-build.util) function from the [*`build`* project](https://pypi.org/project/build/), for example with a small script like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import pathlib

import build.util

def _main():
    args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args_parser.add_argument('path')
    args = args_parser.parse_args()
    path_name = getattr(args, 'path')
    path = pathlib.Path(path_name)
    #
    metadata = build.util.project_wheel_metadata(path)
    version = metadata.get('Version')
    print(version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Or as a one-liner:

```bash
python -c "import build.util; print(build.util.project_wheel_metadata('.').get('Version'))"
```

Comment: It would be up to the build backend to decide how the version is computed, if specified as `dynamic`, yes? So yeah, I don't see a way to avoid building the project in that case.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, that is my understanding as well

Comment: Sigh. I thought they'd finally managed to standardize package meta-data in a declarative format, but I guess this still won't be the final chapter... (jI also ust discovered that the poetry people refuses to put core metadata in the core section..) From the link in your comment I found `python -c "import setuptools;setuptools.setup()" --version` which is both regressive and a bit hacky - so yay :-) ps: your small script can also be a one-liner: `python -c "import build.util as bu; print(bu.project_wheel_metadata('.').get('Version'))"` (not fast, but it works).

Comment: It is standardized, [here is the standard spec](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/). Why the "*Sigh*"? Poetry existed before the standard, they will migrate, but these things take time. They are not refusing to do so, this is not true as far as I know. -- The TOML one-liner is all you need, since even the TOML parsing library is in Python's standard library. What else can one wish?

Comment: Note that `setuptools` is still just one *choice* of 3rd-party build tool. I think your real "complaint" is that Python does not bless any one *build tool* as the standard. The metadata is standardized; access to it is *not*, by intentional design (for better or worse). (That said, it would be nice if `build/__main__.py` exposed a way to query metadata instead of having to cobble something together with `build.util` explicitly.)

Comment: @chepner Something like this? https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/348

Comment: Yes; I poked around there, but clearly not too hard.